# how to generate a sequence from a two dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I was told to generate a sequence of numbers in the picture attached

[image]

The numbers highlighted in blue

For that I used

```
int[][] generate2DArray(int numberOfRows, int noOfColumns){
    int[][] dynamic2DArray = new int[12][12];

    int outerRowLimit = dynamic2DArray.length;
    int innerColumnLimit = dynamic2DArray[0].length;

    int outerLoopCounter = 0;
    int innerLoopCounter = 0;

    while(outerLoopCounter < outerRowLimit){
        while(innerLoopCounter < innerColumnLimit){
            int currentElement = (outerLoopCounter + 1) * (innerLoopCounter + 1);
            dynamic2DArray[outerLoopCounter][innerLoopCounter] = currentElement;
            innerLoopCounter++;
        }
        innerLoopCounter = 0;
        outerLoopCounter++;
    }
    return dynamic2DArray;
}
```

The problem now is that I was told to generate those highlighted in yellow. Can any one help?

I tried `int currentElement = (innerLoopCounter + 10)-2;`

Comment: will rows and columns always be the same?

Comment: For this specific assignment. The number of rows and columns given was 12, 12

Comment: The matrix helps to show the pattern, but there is a closed form expression to generate those sequences so that an actual matrix does not need to be generated.  For the blue sequence, the closed form expression is simply `i * i`, where `i` is the row/column number (starting from 1 not 0).  The closed form expression for the yellow sequence is more complex, but try to work it out on paper. Hint: the sequence is symmetric.  Then translate to code.